# How do I log the IP address a request was received on in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

#### A bit of background

I have a server with 3 IP addresses and 3 `<Host>` elements defined in the `server.xml`.  I'm using IP-based virtual hosts.

I have enabled the [Access Log Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve) on each Host, logging to 3 different log files.

It's working correctly, and I can see the requests logged to the correct files depending on which IP I hit.

So far, so good.

Now I'm trying to diagnose a load balancer issue, so I need to see the IP that each incoming request is hitting.

#### My actual question

According to [the docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve/Attributes) if you include `%A` in the access log pattern it should record the "Local IP address".

eg. `pattern="%h %A %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"`

However, what I'm seeing is requests hitting any of the 3 virtual hosts all show the same Local IP (ie. all 3 logs files show the same Local IP for all requests)

I would expect to see a different Local IP in each log.  I know for certain they have arrived on different IPs, because that's how IP-based virtual hosts works.

I wonder if `%A` is just outputting what Tomcat *thinks* it's IP address is, rather than it actually being the IP the request arrived on.

Is it possible to log the actual IP each request came in on?  Is there a different attribute I should use?

#### Additional info

Server has 3 IPs and hosts file contains:

```
10.10.10.10   localhost
10.10.10.1    serverA
10.10.10.2    serverB
```

My `server.xml` contains:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        connectionTimeout="20000"
        redirectPort="443" server="Unknown"
        useIPVHosts="true" />
...
<engine>
    <Host name="localhost" appBase="C:\webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %A %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>
    </Host>

    <Host name="serverA" appBase="D:\webapps\app01">
        <Context path="/myapp" docBase="D:\webapps\app01" />
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="serverA_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %A %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>
    </Host>

    <Host name="serverB" appBase="D:\webapps\app02">
        <Context path="/myapp" docBase="D:\webapps\app02" />
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="serverB_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %A %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>
    </Host>
</engine>
```

Comment: Do the request URLs actually reference the IP addresses, or the hostnames (serverA, serverB)? If it's the latter, do those names resolve properly on the clients?

Comment: Request URL is like http://app.example.com/myapp This hits a load balancer which distributes traffic to a pool of IPs including 10.10.10.1 and 10.10.10.2 However the requests are going to the wrong virtual host and i can see them in the localhost log